# Null check for Date field on VF Page

Tags: apex, date, datetime, visual

How do I check if a Date field is null?

Below is the code:

```
<apex:outputText label="Date:" value="{0, date,  MM/ dd/ yyyy}" style="text-align:center;" > 
    <apex:param value="{!care.Completion_Date__c}"/>  
</apex:outputText>
```

If value is null I want to show the message 'Value is null'
Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this. Just use the render condition and display two OutputText. Based on the date field it will display output.

```
 <apex:outputText label="Date:" value="{0, date,  MM/ dd/ yyyy}" style="text-align:center;" rendered="{!care.Completion_Date__c != null}"> 
    apex:param value="{!care.Completion_Date__c}"/>  </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText label="Date:" value="Value is null" style="text-align:center;" rendered="{!care.Completion_Date__c == null}"/>
```

Or you can also use VF function to check null validation

```
<apex:outputText label="Date:" value="{0, date,  MM/ dd/ yyyy}" style="text-align:center;" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(care.Completion_Date__c))}">
    apex:param value="{!care.Completion_Date__c}"/>  </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText label="Date:" value="Value is null" style="text-align:center;" rendered="{!ISBLANK(care.Completion_Date__c == null)}"/>
```

Comment: Or `{!NOT(ISBLANK(care.Completion_Date__c))}` and  `{!ISBLANK(care.Completion_Date__c)}`, respectively

Comment: @cropredy  yes we can also use this.